# Term is not removed from content

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy, metadata, term-store, update

We have a term in the term store that we need to remove, but the term that needs to be removed has been used on a lot of pages and documents as metadata.

I thought that by removing the term from the termstore would automatically remove it from content in SharePoint, but that is not the case. The documents and pages are still tagged with the term that I removed, and the term is also still searchable.

I have tried to run powershell command for synchiddenlist for taxonomy, index reset and full crawl without solving my issue. So, I turn to you, fellow SharePoint'ers, for some usable tips.

Comment: You might have to iterate through all your items, edit them, remove the reference, and save the item. You'd think it would automatically clean up, but seeing how disabled users don't get removed from people fields and other similar experiences, running a script to clean them seems necessary.